# Busses routs and probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

Two different and independent buss routes come to the same stop, then both continue to the train station. From route X, there are typically, 2 buses arriving every 10 minutes. While buses from route Y
will arrive at the stop with uniform randomness anywhere from between 0 to 10 minutes since the last bus from route Y.

You arrived at the stop just in time to miss the previous bus, which happened to be from route Y

(a) What is the probability that a Bus from route X will arrive before the next Bus from route Y? (find the joint distribution and set up the integral, no need to evaluate)

For this one, I think y follows a uniform dist, f(y) = 1/10 when y is between 0 and 10. X follows an exponential with beta= 10 from 0 to infinity. and the joint distribution will be (exp(-x/10))/ 100 and the limits of integration would be 0 to 10 for y and from x to infinity for x. Is that correct?

What is the probability that the next bus from route X
and the next bus from route Y
will arrive within a minute from each other?

I have no idea how to do this one.

Please help!thanks!

Comment: It's easier to read your math if you use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

For this question, you're interested in the random variables $T_X$ and $T_Y$ where the outcomes are the waiting times until the next bus from route $X$ and $Y$ arrive respectively.

(a) $T_X$ has an exponential distribution and $T_Y$ has a uniform distribution and you are interested in $P(T_X<T_Y)=P(T_X-T_Y<0)$.

For $T_X$, the mean is $5$ minutes. So $\beta=5$ and the pdf is $$f_{T_X}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{5}e^{-\frac{1}{5}x} & x \ge 0 \\ 0 & otherwise\end{cases}$$

For $T_Y$, the pdf is $$f_{T_Y}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{10} & 0 \le x < 10\\ 0 & otherwise\end{cases}$$

You'll now need to find the pdf of $T_X-T_Y$ using the convolution of the two distributions which will then allow you to integrate and find $P(T_X-T_Y<0)$.

For the next part you're just interested in $P(|T_X-Y_Y| \le 1)=P(-1 \le T_X-Y_Y \le 1)$

---

(Part of the answer I'm not 100% sure on)

The pdf of $T_X-T_Y$ is $$f_{T_X-T_Y}(x)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}{f_{T_X}(x-t)f_{T_Y}(t)\,\,\,dt}$$

$$=\int^{10}_{0}{\frac{1}{10}f_{T_X}(x-t)\,\,\,dt}$$

$$=\begin{cases}0 & x \lt 0 \\\\ \int^{10}_{x}{\frac{1}{50}e^{-\frac{1}{5}(x-t)}\,\,\,dt} & 0 \lt x \lt 10 \\\\ \int^{10}_{0}{\frac{1}{50}e^{-\frac{1}{5}(x-t)}\,\,\,dt} & x \gt 10 \end{cases}$$

Then

$$\int^{10}_{a}{\frac{1}{50}e^{-\frac{1}{5}(x-t)}\,\,\,dt}=\frac{1}{50}e^{-\frac{1}{5}x}\left[5e^{\frac{1}{5}t}\right]^{10}_a$$

$$=\frac{e^2-e^{\frac{1}{5}a}}{10}e^{-\frac{1}{5}x}$$

So

$$f_{T_X-T_Y}(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x \lt 0 \\\\ \frac{1}{10}\left(e^{\left(2-\frac{1}{5}x\right)}-1\right) & 0 \lt x \lt 10 \\\\ \frac{1}{10}(e^2-1)e^{-\frac{1}{5}x} & x \gt 10\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone could verify if what I've done in the bottom part of the answer is correct